# Does Soul Link give life twice in combat and fighting?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Soul Link](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20Link) says:

> Enchant Creature
>
> Whenever enchanted creature deals damage, you gain that much life.
>
> Whenever enchanted creature is dealt damage, you gain that much life.

If the enchanted creature is blocking, does the player gain life from the both the dealing of damage and the takng of damage at the same time?  I would think so since damage is dealt simulateously and there is no reference to "either/or" in the oracle text.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you are correct. When damage is dealt, 2 separate triggered abilities trigger. You will choose the order in which to put them on the stack, and then each one will resolve.

An example: Your Soul Link is enchanting a 3/3 creature, which is blocking a 1/1 attacker. When damage is dealt, your creature will deal 3 damage, and be dealt 1 damage. 2 abilities will trigger: "gain 3 life" and "gain 1 life". You will put them both on the stack, and get a total of 4 life.

Comment: Note that you don't actually gain the life *at the same time* as the OP said - it's two separate triggers. But that's pretty unlikely to matter.

Comment: Oh, never mind, the "at the same time" was probably referring to the damage, not the lifegain!

Comment: [Angel of Vitality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=466758) is an example where it does matter. Since there are two triggers you get two additional life points instead of one.

Comment: @Fax There's about 20 cards that care about life triggers and not amount of life, Archangel of Thune, Ajani's Pridemate, Bloodthirsty Aerialist and Karlov of the Ghost Council are the most notable.